# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; MySQL GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out what could be issue here

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_name .* TO 'db_user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON db_name .* TO 'db_user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION' at line 1
```

MariaDB 10.2.21

Comment: You have a space after db_name. Is that just a typo for this post?

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson no it was on purpose, but closing the space gives the same error

Comment: which mysql version are you using, with mysql 8 you code runs

Comment: @nbk using mysql 14

Comment: that doesn't  exists, do a SELECT version();

Comment: @nbk oh thank you, it's version 10

Comment: try GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db_name`.* TO 'db_user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Comment: @nbk that worked, thanks!